# Good way to develop cache simulator using fifo algorithm on c++

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, fifo

I am trying to develop the cache simulator using fifo algorithm. I understand how the fifo algorithm works, however I have problems with understanding how to implement it. I am provided with template for developing the cache. I wonder about the good way to implement the algorithm.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int opt_assoc, opt_block, opt_capacity, opt_repl, opt_verbose;

typedef struct {
  int set;                      // set ID: 0 ~ (#sets - 1)
  int blk;                      // block ID: 0 ~ (#blocks - 1)
  bool miss;                    // whether this access is a miss
  bool evict;                   // whether eviction happens
  bool is_victim_dirty;         // if evicted, whether the evicted block is dirty
} cache_state_t;

cache_state_t cache(unsigned int addr, char type)
{
    // type: either 'l' or 's'

    cs.miss = true;
    static bool first_time = true;
    if (first_time ) {
        first_time = false;
    }

    cache_state_t cs;

    return cs;
}
```

Comment: `<stdlib.h>`? `typedef struct {`? You should tag your question as "in C99", not "in C++".

Comment: I'm confused by this template. Unless I'm missing something, `cache()` appears to declare `cs` on the stack and return it, in which case it will be deallocated as soon as the function exits. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts exactly!

Comment: May be this will be of some help.... Implementation with codes. Although the implementation is in Java, but you will get the general idea on how to implement it in C. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263004594_Design_and_Implementation_of_a_Simple_Cache_Simulator_in_Java_to_Investigate_MESI_and_MOESI_Coherency_Protocols

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect and incomplete, I think you're just starting to program in C. Use ANSI C programming language (the book) to learn how to implement a doubly linked list or a circular queue, and then go from there.

To give more hints `cache_state_t` will be a node in doubly linked list or a circular queue, once you have filled the cache the next request if its a miss will result in removing the head node of cache and putting the new cache node in the tail.

FIFO cache replacement is normally given in the class assignments, very rarely these strategies are implemented commercially, LRU is the horizon of commercial cache management solutions.

Ideally this should be a comment but then I don't have commenting privileges.

Comment: As I said it`s just a template, so it`s not surprising that it`s incomplete. My concern is the implementation of the algorithm. Im pretty familiar with C, I just want to find out some way to implement the cache.

Comment: Don't feel offended but what sort of template would declare the variable later and assign the value before. I'm sorry but for a pseudo code too your example doesn't add up. But we are all there to help. The DS you have to use is a Circular Queue where the size of queue is the size of your cache.